# ¿error al subir imagen con laravel?

Tags: php, html5, laravel, crud

Tengo un formulario en el cual guardo una imagen, guardo la imagen en la carpeta con éxito, pero la nueva ruta de la imagen con su nuevo nombre no se guarda en la base de datos.
Guarda algo como:

```
 "C:\xampp\tmp\php71AA.tmp"`
```

Esta es la parte que uso para obtener la nueva dirección:

```
 $input -> imagen_producto = asset($path);
```

Aquí dejo el código del controlador.

```
public function store(CreateproductoRequest $request)
{

$input = $request->all();

if($request->file('imagen_producto'))
{
$path = Storage::disk('public')->put('image',$request->file('imagen_producto'));
$input -> imagen_producto = asset($path);
  }

    $producto = $this->productoRepository->create($input);
    Flash::success('Producto saved successfully.');
    return redirect(route('producto.index'));
}
```

Comment: Tengo otro problema. Cuando subo las imágenes todo anda bien, pero cuando elijo una imagen que tiene un guion u otro carácter especial, en el formulario mi tira que no se pudo subir la imagen. Que podría Ser ??

Comment: Ya lo solucione, no eran los guiones, es porque los archivos eran muy pesados. Solo cambie el máximo de mb de uploads en php.ini max_execution_time = 1000
max_input_time = 1000
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/117327)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listo
Cambie esta linea:

```
$input -> imagen_producto = asset($path);
```

Por esta:

```
$input['imagen_producto'] = $path;
```

Estas lineas guardan el nuevo nombre de la imagen. En la primer linea con "asset" obtenía el nombre y la dirección completa de donde esta la imagen subida. En la segunda linea obtengo nombre del directorio donde guarde la imagen y el nombre de la misma. Pero en la primer linea no guardaba nada en el objeto del formulario "imagen_producto", en la segunda si guarda correctamente el nuevo nombre de la imagen. Sin embargo decidí no usar "asset" aunque lo pude usar.

Comment: recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada si resolviste el problema

Comment: me dice que en dos días.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución Neftalí, agrega una explicación de lo que realiza el cambio, esto sería útil para la comunidad, revisa [answer], saludos!

Answer (score 0):

En tu base de datos debieses guardar solamente el nombre de tu imagen y luego acceder a ella con {{ asset('directorio'/'nombre imagen') }}. En nombre imagen debes rescatar lo que se guardo en la base de datos